# laravel image validation is always working even when the file is an image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

i am trying to upload an image to my database 
the problem is when i use the validator , it always return tru showing the error the avatar file should be an image even when i am puttin an image , i tried jpeg,pjg and png but nothing seems to work

controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this -> validate($request ,[
            //other validators working fine
            'avatar' => ['nullable', 'image' ],


    ]);

    if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        // Get filename with the extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName();
        // Get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ext
        $extension = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // Filename to store
        $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        // Upload Image
        $path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs('public/avatars', $fileNameToStore);
    } else {
        $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
    }

         $member= new Member;
         //other inputs working fine
         $member->avatar = $fileNameToStore;

         $member->save(); 
    }
```

view

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="avatar" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">image du membre</label>

   <div class="col-md-6">
       <input id="avatar" type="file" class=" @error('avatar') is-invalid @enderror" name="avatar"  autofocus>

   @error('avatar')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
          <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
      </span>
   @enderror
 </div>
```

when i tired removing the validators it works and always getting noimage in the database

Comment: Try removing 'nullable' from validator

Comment: worked , but why

Comment: nullable
The field under validation may be null. This is particularly useful when validating primitive such as strings and integers that can contain null values. I guess it doesn't work for files.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also:

```
$this -> validate($request ,[
    //other validators working fine

    ]);
if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
    $this -> validate($request ,[
             'avatar' => 'image',
    ]);
}
```

First u validate form then, if file is present, validate image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change like this in your form

```
<form action="{{url('')}}/your_action" method="POST" id="" name="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```